# Need help in table detection using Tesserocr -Python

Tags: python, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using python 3.7 and tesseract 4.00 and i am trying to do table detection using tesseract .

I followed the approach given inside the discussion [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1714) but inside the current code while the blocktype for all the elements are coming as 1 i.e "UNKNOWN"

For your reference I am giving the reference of the block types that exist in tesseract

- UNKNOWN: Type is not yet known. Keep as the first element.
- FLOWING_TEXT: Text that lives inside a column.
- HEADING_TEXT: Text that spans more than one column.
- PULLOUT_TEXT: Text that is in a cross-column pull-out region.
- EQUATION: Partition belonging to an equation region.
- INLINE_EQUATION: Partition has inline equation.
- TABLE: Partition belonging to a table region.
- VERTICAL_TEXT: Text-line runs vertically.
- CAPTION_TEXT: Text that belongs to an image.
- FLOWING_IMAGE: Image that lives inside a column.
- HEADING_IMAGE: Image that spans more than one column.
- PULLOUT_IMAGE: Image that is in a cross-column pull-out region.
- HORZ_LINE: Horizontal Line.
- VERT_LINE: Vertical Line.
- NOISE: Lies outside of any column.
- COUNT: Count

[Tesserocr-API](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/blob/master/tesserocr.pyx)

class TableDetector:

```
__TRAINED_DATA_PATH = #Tessdata path 

def detect_table(self, image, tx_id, do_pre_process=True):
    try:
        pre_processed_image = image
        if do_pre_process:
            pre_processed_image = cvtColor(image, COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            pre_processed_image = medianBlur(pre_processed_image, 3)
            pre_processed_image = GaussianBlur(pre_processed_image, (3, 3), 0)
        conf_score = 0

        with PyTessBaseAPI(psm=6, oem=1, lang="eng",
                           path=self.__TRAINED_DATA_PATH) as api:
            pil_image = Image.fromarray(pre_processed_image)
            api.SetImage(pil_image)


            api.SetVariable("textord_tabfind_find_tables", "true")
            api.SetVariable("textord_tablefind_recognize_tables", "true")
            api.SetVariable("textord_show_tables", "true")
            api.SetVariable("textord_tablefind_show_stats", "true")
            x=api.AnalyseLayout()
            # level = RIL.BLOCK
            for e in iterate_level(x, RIL.BLOCK):
                print(e.Orientation())
                print(e.BlockType())
    except Exception as e:
        Logger.log.error("Error in image_to_data : %s" % e, exc_info=True)

    return result_dec
```

Comment: An alternative approach is to use OpenCV with thresholding + contour area filtering to detect the grid. From here you can remove the horizontal and vertical lines then perform OCR with pytesseract. Maybe add an input image?

Comment: HI nathancy ,I have many invoices that are having tables with boundaries and some dont and in some invoices there are redundant data which are inside the external contour while extraction so the y+h coordinate that i get is not correct .My main aim for getting to have tesseract todetect table is that i get the end point from the table .I want to get the exact ending coordinates of the table in an image .Rest of the algorithm i have completed .

You can take a look at any invoices on google , sorry i cant share the images i am working on but they are mainly invoices of different types.